# Symfony Bundle constructor arguments not passed (Autowire not working for custom bundle)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6, symfony-bundle

I am developing a bundle `JohnCorpFormsBundle` for my own symfony projects to share extended form logic.

However, when implementing the bundle in a project `myproject` I always get an error when I load a page in `myproject` that relies on bundle logic.

**Error Message**:

> **Too few arguments** to function
> `JohnCorp\FormsBundle\Form\Builder\Core\ListFilterType::__construct()`,
> **0 passed** in `/var/www/myproject/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php` on `line 81` and exactly **1 expected**

It seems, the parameter `$requestStack` is not being passsed to `ListFilterType::__construct()` but shouldn't this work automatically using autowire?

---

MyProject: **Controller-Code** that causes the error:

```
// UserListController.php

use JohnCorps\FormsBundle\Form\Builder\Core\ListFilterType;
// ...

// this line runs into the error:
$listFilterForm = $this->createForm(ListFilterType::class);
```

Bundle: **Form class:**

```
// ListFilterType::class

namespace JohnCorp\FormsBundle\Form\Builder\Core;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class ListFilterType extends AbstractType
{

    protected RequestStack $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    //...
```

Bundle: **Extension**

```
// src/DependencyInjection/JohnCorpFormsExtension.php

namespace JohnCorp\FormsBundle\DependencyInjection;

class JohnCorpFormsExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}
```

Bundle: **composer.json** autoload

```
{
  "name": "johncorp/forms-bundle",
  "type": "symfony-bundle",
  
  ...

  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "JohnCorp\\FormsBundle\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

---

I tried adding the arguments explicitly in the bundles `services.yaml` to ensure autowire is not a problem, but that does not change a thing.

Bundle: **src/Resources/config/services.yaml**:

```
services:
    JohnCorp\FormsBundle\Form\Builder\Core\ListFilterType:
        arguments:
            $requestStack: '@request_stack'
```

I am not sure if this is required or if it is loaded. (I include this in a `src/DependencyInjection/JohnCorpFormsExtension.php`)

**I also tried** adding the `yaml`-Code from above directly inside the **projects `services.yaml`** without any effect.

---

**I also tried** explicitly using **autowire**-Attribute in `ListFilterType.php`

```
// ListFilterType::class

public function __construct(
    #[Autowire(service: 'request_stack')] RequestStack $requestStack
)
```

---

Comment: You need an [extension class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html) to load the services.yaml file.  Since you tagged this as S6 you should also probably use the latest bundle directory structure so just a `config` directory instead of `Resources/config`.  And if you are not already then you should definitely be using the newly introduced [AbstractBundle](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-1-simpler-bundle-extension-and-configuration) class.

Comment: I have a `src/DependencyInjection/JohnCorpFormsExtension` class already to load the `services.yaml`. I have also two `config` directories, `./config/bundles.php` and `./src/Resources/config/services.yaml` are you sure I have to mix these?

Comment: You absolutely do not want to mix things.  Please consider updating your question with your extension code.  If in fact you are correctly loading services.yaml then you explicit configuration should work.  Also, please indicate if you are using the AbstractBundle class and, if not, then why not.

Comment: Alright. I added the missing code of the Extension.

Comment: Okay.  So you went old style but it still should work.  Does `bin/console debug:container ListFilterType` show anything useful?  If not then introduce a deliberate error in your services.yaml file and see if clearing the cache generates an error message.

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction! Thank you! The error is, that the `JohnCorpFormsExtension.php` is not being loaded. Although I dont know why, **it works when I manually load the `services.yaml`** inside the `JohnCorpFormsBundle::loadExtension()` via `$container->import('../config/services.yaml')`! *I moved the services.yaml as well, as you recommended*.
I **also had to** add `autowire:true` and `autoconfigure:true` in `services.yaml` as @rapaelec stated. Since its a in-house bundle this may be fine, although I'd rather had it work without autowire. Anyways, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Symfony 6 , you just have to set the autowire and autoconfigure as true in your Bundle like this :

```
# yourBundle/src/Ressources/config/services.yaml
services:
    JohnCorp\FormsBundle\Form\Builder\Core\ListFilterType:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
```

here is the doc : [service-container-services-load-example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example)

then after that you have to inject your service in your BundleExtension:

```
<?php
//yourBundle/src/DepencencyInjection/YourBundleExtension
namespace App\YourBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class YourBundleExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
...
}
```

Comment: This is not the issue here, autowiring is not working because op is working inside a bundle and need to configure which services his bundle uses explicitly.

Comment: In a sense you are both wrong but for different reasons.  @DylanKAS autowire is not recommended for shared bundles but still works just fine.  The posted answer is missing the resources section which indicates where the bundle's code lives and is missing that fact that you need to explicitly load your services file.

Comment: I mean he have to add this autowire and autoconfigure in his Bundle directly , on hisBundle/config/services.yaml

Comment: @rapaelec Merely adding the file will do nothing.  Even if the file you posted was complete.  Might want to review the bundle documentation to see how the services.yaml file are loaded in a bundle.

Comment: @Cerad I did say autowiring is not working, not that it cannot work. And that he should configure his services explicitly instead of autowiring

Comment: @Cerad ok , I'll update the response do explain more about how to inject the service after

Comment: I tried stating `autowire` and `autoconfig` like advised, instead of the explicit parameter `$requestStack`, but it does not work either.

Comment: I updated the response about first how to add the services , and then how to load it , hope this is more clear now :D

Comment: Thanks rapaelec. I am sorry I forgot to add the code of my `Extension`-class which looks *quite* similar to yours. I added it to the question above. Do I miss anything?

Comment: normally it looks good , even if you don't forgot all the namespaces :p

Comment: Thanks @rapaelec! It works now with your help and @Cerad's help. My Extension-Class is not loaded at all, so **I loaded the `services.yaml` manually** in my `JohnCorpFormsBundle::loadExtension()`. I also had to set `autowire:true` and `autoconfigure:true` in `services.yaml` as you recommended. Only with these two changes it works.